# Are there situations outside of set theory where it would be useful if $\mathrm{ICF}$ were true?

Tags: set-theory

Write $\mathrm{ICF}$ for the "injective continuum function hypothesis" i.e. the sentence of ZFC expressing that

$$2^X \cong 2^Y \rightarrow X \cong Y$$

for all sets $X$ and $Y$, where $\cong$ denotes equipotency.

If I understand correctly:

1. $\mathrm{ICF}$ is independent of $\mathrm{ZFC}$.
2. $\mathrm{GCH}$ implies $\mathrm{ICF}.$ (In the presence of the $\mathrm{ZFC}$ axioms.)
3. The converse of 2 is false.

**Question.** Are there situations outside set theory (e.g. group theory, measure theory, etc.) where it would be useful if $\mathrm{ICF}$ were true, irrespective of whether or not $\mathrm{GCH}$ is true?

Comment: "Some reason" :-) Those are two different $\rm C$'s.

Comment: Also, I recall some talk about matroids and there was an example which required $\sf ICF$ to hold and $\sf CH$ to fail. I'll try to dig out the details.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that would be great! I thought matroids were finite though, so I'm surprised ICF matters in that field.

Comment: You probably thought that graphs were finite too, before you knew the harsh truth of reality!

Comment: Here's one from, uh, Lattice Theory. If two complete atomic Boolean algebras have the same cardinality, then they are isomorphic.

Comment: @bof: That's an excellent example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the theory of infinite matroids one can talk about a basis of a matroid. Higgs proved that $\sf GCH$ implies that if $\cal M$ is a matroid on a set $E$, then every two bases of $\cal M$ have the same cardinality.

However a close inspection of the proof shows that in fact we need two facts which follow from $\sf GCH$ (but do not imply it, even in conjunction):

1. $\sf ICF$, and
2. For every infinite set $X$ there exists a chain of subsets of size $2^{|X|}$ in $\mathcal P(X)$.

I'm not 100% sure whether or not the second is implied by the first, and I am inclined to believe that the answer to that is negative. But this is an example of somewhere that $\sf ICF$ explicitly shows up in the proof.

For some more information: **[Stefan Geschke - An invitation to infinite matroids (slides)](http://settheory.mathtalks.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Geschke.pdf)**

Comment: Sweet. Does Axiom 2 have a name? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: Not that I know of. It's more of a model theoretic thing, methinks.

Comment: If its not very complicated, can you explain why GCH proves 2? I get that under GCH it reads "For every ordinal $\alpha,$ there exists a subchain of $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ of cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$," but why should that be true?

Comment: As I said, this is somewhat model theoretic, as far as I know. So I can't really give you a short explanation... Sorry

Comment: Fair enough, but is the case $\alpha=0$ any easier? Sorry if I'm hassling you.

Comment: Of course. In that case it is true in ZF. Consider Dedekind cuts.

Comment: Oh yeah! $\;\!\;$

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if (2) implies that (2'): every infinite set $X$ has the property that there is a total ordering $\leq$ of $X$ such that the completion of $(X,\leq)$ by Dedekind-cuts has $2^X$ elements. (2) certainly follows from (2').

Comment: Stands to reason that maybe.

Answer (score 8):

This is addressing two questions of user18921 asked in the comments to Asaf's answer.

a) The reason why GCH gives long chains in $\mathcal P(X)$ is the following:
For an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ let $L=\{0,1\}^\kappa$ and let $B$ be the set of all sequences in $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ that are eventually 0 (or constant, it doesn't matter).  The size of $B$ is $\sup\{2^\lambda:\lambda<\kappa\}$.
$L$ is linearly ordered by the lexicographic ordering and $B$ is dense in $L$.  Assuming GCH we have 
$2^\lambda\leq\kappa$ for all $\lambda<\kappa$ (this is all of GCH that we need).
Hence $|B|=\kappa$.  Let $X=B$.  Now the family of sets $\{x\in B:x<y\}$, $y\in L$, is a chain in $\mathcal P(X)$ of size $2^{|X|}$.

b) (2) is equivalent to (2').  One half of this is already hidden in my answer a):
If there is an infinite linear order of size $|X|$ whose completion is of size $2^{|X|}$, then $\mathcal P(X)$ has a chain of length $2^{|X|}$.

On the other hand, assume $\mathcal P(X)$ has a chain $\mathcal C$ of length $2^{|X|}$.  We may assume that $\mathcal C$ is closed under infinite intersections
and that it contains $X$.
Now for each $x\in X$ consider the first $A\in\mathcal C$ with $x\in A$
and call it $A_x$.  By our assumptions on $\mathcal C$, $A_x$ exists for all $x\in X$.  It is just the intersection of all $A\in\mathcal C$ with $x\in A$.

Now $\mathcal A=\{A_x:x\in X\}$ is a dense subset of the linearly ordered set $\mathcal C$ ($\mathcal C$ is ordered by $\subseteq$, of course).
$\mathcal A$ is a linear order of size $|X|$ with a completion of size $2^{|X|}$.

The equivalence of (2) and (2') was observed independently by Baumgartner and Mitchell, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Nice of you to stop by! :-)